# delete rows from destination table ssis using source flat file

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a table which contains year specific records, we change the values based on criteria that is specific to the particular year we are in.  I get weekly updates to the information, sometimes with new products that are added or deleted products or changes to the products.  We have simplified the process and right now we manually delete the records for the current year and then load the source data for the year in its entirety.  I am trying to automate this process.  I have an Execute SQL Task that deletes the records that are for the current year, but I have hard coded the value.  What I would like to do is make this a parameter based on a field in the flat file that I importing.  So my question is this, can I create a parameter based on the flat file and use it prior to the dataflow task?  Or do I have to do a dataflow task to create the parameter, then the SQL task and then another dataflow task?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a script task to pre-read your flat file and populate a package variable.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of how this is done or point me to a resource.  I have never used script tasks before.

Comment: Start here:   https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=ssis+script+task+to+read+&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4GGNI_enUS551US551&q=ssis+script+task+to+read+text+file&gs_l=hp..2.0l3j0i22i30l2.0.0.7.3589046...........0.cTcIVOY63jQ

Answer (score 0):

[image]

and then in the script

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Math
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper

Public Class ScriptMain
Inherits UserComponent
Dim intfield As Integer

Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)
    '
    ' Add your code here
    '
    intfield = Row.Myfield
End Sub
Public Overrides Sub PostExecute()
    Me.Variables.MyVariable = intfield
End Sub
End Class
```

For completeness you could then display the variable (while testing). 
Note: You can disable this Script task once testing is complete! 
Add A script component in the Control flow (see image below)

[image]

Then in the script add this to display the variable contents.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Math
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime

Public Class ScriptMain
Public Sub Main()
    MsgBox(Dts.Variables("MyVariable").Value.ToString)
    Dts.TaskResult = Dts.Results.Success
End Sub
End Class
```